# SimpleXML Problem

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, authorize.net

Maybe someone can help me with a problem I am having regarding SimpleXML Objects.

I am integrating with the authorize.net CIM manager and sending in a customer profile. When I sent it in, the raw xml response is passed through a parser and turned into a SimpleXML object.

Here is the code that is used to submit the request:

```
$content =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>".
        "<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">".
        MerchantAuthenticationBlock().
        "<profile>".
        //"<merchantCustomerId>".$userInsertedId."</merchantCustomerId>". // Your own identifier for the customer.
        "<description>'New User Purchase'</description>".
        "<email>" . $_GET["email"] . "</email>".
        "<paymentProfiles>".
        "<billTo>".
         "<firstName>".$_GET["firstname"]."</firstName>".
         "<lastName>".$_GET["lastname"]."</lastName>".
         "<address>".$_GET["street"]."</address>".
         "<city>".$_GET["city"]."</city>".
         "<state>".$_GET["state"]."</state>".
         "<zip>".$_GET["zip"]."</zip>".
         "<country>".$_GET["country"]."</country>".
         "<phoneNumber>".$_GET["phone"]."</phoneNumber>".
        "</billTo>".
        "<payment>".
         "<creditCard>".
          "<cardNumber>".$_GET["number"]."</cardNumber>".
          "<expirationDate>".$_GET["year"]."-".$_GET["month"]."</expirationDate>". // required format for API is YYYY-MM
          "<cardCode>".$_GET["code"]."</cardCode>".
         "</creditCard>".
         "</payment>".
        "</paymentProfiles>".
        "</profile>".
        "<validationMode>testMode</validationMode>". 
        "</createCustomerProfileRequest>";

        $CCresponse = send_xml_request($content);

        //echo($CCresponse);

        $parsedresponse = parse_api_response($CCresponse);

   function parse_api_response($content)
        {
            $parsedresponse = simplexml_load_string($content, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            if ("Ok" != $parsedresponse->messages->resultCode) 
            {
                echo "The operation failed with the following errors:<br>";
                foreach ($parsedresponse->messages->message as $msg) 
                {
                    echo "[" . htmlspecialchars($msg->code) . "] " . htmlspecialchars($msg->text) . "<br>";
                }
                    echo "<br>";
            }
            return $parsedresponse;
        }
```

When I do the following:

```
$parsedresponse = parse_api_response($CCresponse);
print_r($parsedresponse);
```

I get the following output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[messages] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [resultCode] => Ok
        [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [code] => I00001
                [text] => Successful.
            )
    )
[customerProfileId] => 15642446
[customerPaymentProfileIdList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [numericString] => 13865552
    )
[customerShippingAddressIdList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )
[validationDirectResponseList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [string] => 1|1|1|(TESTMODE) This transaction has been approved.|000000|P|0|none|Test transaction for ValidateCustomerPaymentProfile.|1.00|CC|auth_only||*****|******||****|*******|******|******|USA|1234567890||email@email.com|none|none|none|none|none|none|none|none|0.00|0.00|0.00|FALSE|none|207BCBBF78E85CF174C87AE286B472D2|||||||||||||*******|*******||||||||||||||||
    )
)
 )
)
```

So from this is looks like all is working. But when I try and drill into the SimpleXML object, and do this:

```
echo $code = (string) $parsedresponse->messages->resultCode;
```

I am getting an output of "OkOk", it seems like it is running over it twice. This has been driving me absolutely crazy and I can't figure out what the heck is going on here. Can someone please point me in the right direction here so I can get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason for this is probably elsewhere  in your code. What do you do with `$code`?

Comment: nothing, I just created that variable for the sake of echo-ing it back out.

Comment: @ackerchez can you show the full code?

Comment: @Pekka  Original question edited to show full code

Comment: @acker try the following: `echo (string) $parsedresponse->messages->resultCode." X ";` If you get `Ok X Ok X`, you are outputting the variable twice somewhere. Add `__LINE__` to see where. If you get `OkOk X`, there's indeed some weirdness

Comment: cannot reproduce the error: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZBIoAd -

Comment: @Pekka ok so I added in the "x" and did get "Ok X Ok X"  What do you mean by adding in _Line_

Comment: @acker disregard that "line" idea, I realized it's B.S. Anyway, that line with the `echo` gets executed twice. I do not believe you are showing us all your code. Do you have a loop running?

Comment: that code is just sitting in an else if statement, nothing more.

Comment: Install a debugger (like XDebug or Zend Debugger) and step through the code. This will tell you where it is echo'ed for the second time.

Comment: weird, when i place this code into a directory itself with no other files it seems to work alright. I get one response back. I am struggling now to figure out the differences...

Comment: OK, so I did some work on all the other files that were added via "require_once" and I think there might have been a conflict there. I was under the impression that if you use "require_once" then even if you are bringing that same file into a different file which was already included, it will be ignored. Is that not true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you could try and use the xpath method to navigate the SimpleXMLElement like this:

```
$code = (string) $parsedresponse->xpath('messages/resultCode');
echo $code;
```